# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{50}\left[\frac{1}{49+r} - \frac{1}{2r(2r-1)}\right]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find 
$$
S=\sum_{r=1}^{50}\left[\frac{1}{49+r} - \frac{1}{2r(2r-1)}\right]
$$
Thus, some terms are in harmonic progression.

I tried to rearrange $S$ and represent it as a sum of two terms.

Comment: So what is $HP$, and why wouldn't you spell it out anyway?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I believe it's harmonic progression.

Comment: The answer is $$\frac{1}{100}$$ by the way. Still figuring out the working...

Comment: You need a $\sum$ symbol on the second one$\ldots$

Comment: $New$ user info: Please, you must always show what you tried. That enhances the possibility that MSE-people pay attention to your post. In addition, read the [MSE-$\LaTeX$-$\texttt{MathJax}$ Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

$S=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{50}\left[\frac{1}{49+r} - \frac{1}{2r(2r-1)}\right]$

The first part of the sum:

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{50}\frac{1}{49+r}=\sum\limits_{r=50}^{99}\frac{1}{r}=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{99}\frac{1}{r}-\sum\limits_{r=1}^{49}\frac{1}{r}$

The second part of the sum:

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{50} - \frac{1}{2r(2r-1)}=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{50}\big( \frac{1}{2r}{-\frac{1}{(2r-1)}}\big)=\frac{1}{100}-\sum\limits_{r=1}^{99}\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r}$

Finally

$S=\frac{1}{100}+\sum\limits_{r=1}^{99}\big(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{(-1)^{r-1}}{r}\big)-\sum\limits_{r=1}^{49}\frac{1}{r}$ as the 99. term is equal to zero in the first part of the sum and $r=2k$ we get the followings:

$S=\frac{1}{100}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{49}\frac{2}{2k}-\sum\limits_{r=1}^{49}\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{100}$